# Are there any apocryphal writings on the apparent gap between Verses 4 and 5 of John 2?

Tags: gospel-of-john, miracles, apocrypha

We see in John 2:3-5, a prelude to the Miracle at Cana:

> <sup>**3**</sup> When the wine gave out, the mother of Jesus said to him, “They have no wine.” <sup>**4**</sup> And Jesus said to her, “Woman, what concern is that to you and to me? My hour has not yet come.” <sup>**5**</sup> His mother said to the servants, “Do whatever he tells you.

See that in Verse 4, Jesus declines to get involved. Then, in Verse 5, Mary tells the servants to follow Jesus' instructions. Apparently, there is a gap between the two verses. Did Jesus say something like:  "OK, OK...Mother, just because you are pressuring me to re-set my time, I will do something about it"?  Or, did Mary say something like "See the plight of the host, my son; how will he face the guests? I know you will do something from your side?" However, John does not give a narrative of what went in between the communications in Verses 4 and 5.

Are there any apocryphal writings on the apparent gap between Verses 4 and 5 of John 2?

Answer (score 1):

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints have a [Joseph Smith Translation](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/jst/introduction?lang=eng) on [v4](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/john/2?lang=eng&id=4#4?lang=eng)

> Jesus saith unto her, Woman, what *wilt thou have me to do for* thee? *that will I do; for* mine hour is not yet come.

This changes the meaning from not willing to get involved to being willing to do whatever his mother asks.

---

<sub>While JST is not included in apocryphal writings by LDS belief, going off of the [definition](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bd/apocrypha?lang=eng): `Secret or hidden. By this word is generally meant those sacred books of the Jewish people that were not included in the Hebrew Bible` the JST could fall under this category as it is generally not included in other denominations/versions of the bible, non LDS might consider it apocryphal. JST: `The Lord inspired the Prophet Joseph Smith to restore truths to the King James Bible text that had become lost or changed since the original words were written.`</sub>

Comment: Please don't take offence, because no offence is intended, but are you proposing that Joseph Smith's Translation is an apocryphal writing?

Comment: @Lesley no JST is not included in apocryphal writings (and not LDS doctrine/belief), however going off of the definition: `Secret or hidden. By this word is generally meant those sacred books of the Jewish people that were not included in the Hebrew Bible` the JST is generally not included in other denominations/versions of the bible and could be. I felt that this was a different version of the scriptures in question, with better clarity so answered.

Comment: @depperm It might as well be secret or hidden for what almost anybody in mainstream Christianity knows of it. The apocrypha are at many points better known, and more traveled.